# JQuery Promise failing on ComponentDidMount React.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, es6-promise

In my components' ComponentDidMount life cycle method, I'm attempting to initiate an AJAX request to get data client-side (Data needs to be available when app has loaded). Upon inspection, I've noticed that my promise chain keeps deferring to the `fail` property. This is confusing because, upon inspection via the Chrome Developer tools, the request is made and data is successfully returned to the promise (see Screenshot). I suspected it could be the speed at how fast my component loads, and I tried a componentWillMount life cycle method, and it yields the same results. I was retrieving data fine, synchronously via an AJAX request, but I'm now trying to improve the code with asynchronously functionality.

new code tried:

```
componentDidMount: function(){ 
      var returnedClassesString;

      var user = window.globalValue;

      function getQueries(user){
          returnedClassesString = $.ajax("/portals/0/js/get_classes_front.aspx?userName="+user).done(function(data,err){
              console.log('good' + data);
          }).fail(function(data,err){
              console.log(err);
          });  

      }

      getQueries(user);



  },
```

componentDidMount method:

```
componentDidMount: function(){ 
      var returnedClassesString;

      var user = window.globalValue;

       $.when($.ajax("/portals/0/js/get_classes_front.aspx?userName="+user)).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // Handle both XHR objects
          console.log(data);
          }).fail(function(){
                   console.log('failed');
             });
    }
```

Screenshot of Chrome Dev-Tools (Network Traffic, I request the first file in the stack):
[image]

Screenshot of Chrome Dev-Tools (JavaScript console w/ 'failed' message):
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is in the ajax request. Use `$.ajax(...).done().fail()` instead of `$.when($.ajax()).then().fail()`. Does the response have anything in the body? What type of data you should be retrieving?

Comment: Hey, I actually just tried this, and got 'failed' again. This time though, I logged out the error code which was 'parseerror' (spelled like such). I'm expected back a string of data. I used a AJAX request when getting the data synchronously, and had no issue, and I also tried $.get(). I was trying $.when because I have more than 1 AJAX request I would be waiting to resolve

Comment: I'm about to post some new code I tried

Comment: The dev tools shows that the response is "script", examine it and see what it looks like. Is it JSON? Do the response headers say it should be parsed as JSON? Can you paste the response headers and body here?

Comment: "parseerror" means your JSON is not valid.

Comment: Ok, let me check my client side code. 1 sec

Comment: @DaveMethvin That was the issue on my server side. Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; changed to Response.ContentType = "text";

Answer (score 0):

Issue was on my server-side code. Using .Net code-behind, switched `Response.ContentType` from `Response.ContentType = "text/xml";` to `Response.ContentType = "text";`. Thank You to [Dave Methvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074442/dave-methvin) for spotting out my JSON error. Code posted above in both examples still valid.